# Why can't I use the equation for centripetal acceleration to solve for acceleration in this problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

A small car with mass
0.800 kg travels at constant
speed on the inside of a track
that is a vertical circle with
radius 5.00 m. If
the normal force exerted by the
track on the car when it is at the
top of the track (point B) is 6.00
N, what is the normal force on
the car when it is at the bottom
of the track (point A)?

Now, I have already solved for the problem using other methods, but the first time I did it, I used the formula a=v^2/r - this gave me an incorrect acceleration. I got 28.8 m/s^2, when in fact the acceleration was 17.3 m/s^2, because they solved for acceleration using the equation of the normal force at point B (N = ma - mg).

So why didn't the standard equation for acceleration work? In the problem, it never explicitly stated which velocity it has, but in the figure next to it, a diagram was drawn showing a tangential velocity of 12.0 m/s. I've checked other sites and it was said that you don't need a velocity, but why couldn't I use it anyway, since it was given? People are saying that the diagram is mislabeled, but I find it hard to believe that the textbook would do this.

[image: PICTURE]

Comment: Well, the velocity is not $12\ \rm{m/s}$ for one thing.

Comment: @AaronStevens It's given to use in the picture next to it. 12.0 m/s doesn't work, I agree, but for some reason it's shown in the picture. I included a link to the problem for reference.

Comment: @AngoMango You're right.  The picture and the text are inconsistent.  You should not be surprised about this.  All your other instincts are correct.  Don't let this rattle you.

Comment: Thanks, @Mike. I'll just accept that the picture is inaccurate. I'll have a talk with my professor tomorrow morning.

Comment: Yeah, there are probably thousands of exercises in your book, so you can't expect them to get every little detail right on every one of them.  Maybe the illustrator was looking at an older version of the question, or maybe the figure is reused for a different question and they didn't realize there was a conflict.  Anyway, the most common problem I see in early physics students is that they don't have enough faith in themselves.  Don't make that mistake again.  :)

Comment: Well, ignoring the wrong diagram, you don't need the velocity to answer the question, and you don't actually need the radius either.